# Why does Spark standalone report "ExecutorLostFailure (executor driver lost)" with cogroup?

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I am using `cogroup` functionality (for two dataset one 9 GB and the other 110 KB) running Spark in standalone mode as shown below:

I have 128 GB ram and 24 cores. My configurations are:

```
set("spark.executor.memory","64g")
set("spark.driver.memory","64g")
```

IntelliJ VM options: `-Xmx128G`

As you can see from the code I have partition the data into 1000 parts. I've also tried 5000 and 10000 respectively since `countByKey` is very expensive in my case.

From some other StackOverflow posts I have seen `spark.default.parallelism` option. How should I tune my configurations? Do I need to add something more to IntelliJ VM options? Should I use `spark.default.parallelism`?

```
val emp = sc.textFile("\\text1.txt",1000).map{line => val s = line.split("\t"); (s(3),s(1))}
val emp_new = sc.textFile("\\text2.txt",1000).map{line => val s = line.split("\t"); (s(3),s(1))}

val cog = emp.cogroup(emp_new)
val skk = cog.flatMap {
            case (key: String, (l1: Iterable[String], l2: Iterable[String])) =>
              for { e1 <- l1.toSeq; e2 <- l2.toSeq } yield ((e1, e2), 1)
          }
val com = skk.countByKey()
```

When 1000 and 5000 partitions are used `countByKey` ends up too much spilling, when 10000 partition is used I started to get some results at least some tasks are finished. But after a while I got such errors as shown below:

```
15/10/06 14:01:17 WARN HeartbeatReceiver: Removing executor driver with no recent heartbeats: 451457 ms exceeds timeout 120000 ms
15/10/06 14:01:17 ERROR TaskSchedulerImpl: Lost executor driver on localhost: Executor heartbeat timed out after 451457 ms
15/10/06 14:01:17 INFO TaskSetManager: Re-queueing tasks for driver from TaskSet 2.0
15/10/06 14:01:17 WARN TaskSetManager: Lost task 109.0 in stage 2.0 (TID 20111, localhost): ExecutorLostFailure (executor driver lost)
15/10/06 14:01:17 ERROR TaskSetManager: Task 109 in stage 2.0 failed 1 times; aborting job
15/10/06 14:01:17 INFO DAGScheduler: Resubmitted ShuffleMapTask(2, 91), so marking it as still running
15/10/06 14:01:17 WARN TaskSetManager: Lost task 34.0 in stage 2.0 (TID 20036, localhost): ExecutorLostFailure (executor driver lost)
15/10/06 14:01:17 INFO DAGScheduler: Resubmitted ShuffleMapTask(2, 118), so marking it as still running
15/10/06 14:01:17 INFO DAGScheduler: Resubmitted ShuffleMapTask(2, 100), so marking it as still running
15/10/06 14:01:17 INFO DAGScheduler: Resubmitted ShuffleMapTask(2, 76), so marking it as still running
```

...

```
15/10/06 14:01:17 INFO TaskSchedulerImpl: Cancelling stage 2
15/10/06 14:01:17 INFO DAGScheduler: ShuffleMapStage 2 (countByKey at ngram.scala:39) failed in 1020,915 s
15/10/06 14:01:17 INFO DAGScheduler: Job 0 failed: countByKey at ngram.scala:39, took 3025,563964 s
Exception in thread "main" org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 109 in stage 2.0 failed 1 times, most recent failure: Lost task 109.0 in stage 2.0 (TID 20111, localhost): ExecutorLostFailure (executor driver lost)
Driver stacktrace:
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.org$apache$spark$scheduler$DAGScheduler$$failJobAndIndependentStages(DAGScheduler.scala:1273)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$abortStage$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:1264)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$abortStage$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:1263)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ResizableArray$class.foreach(ResizableArray.scala:59)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.foreach(ArrayBuffer.scala:47)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.abortStage(DAGScheduler.scala:1263)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:730)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:730)
    at scala.Option.foreach(Option.scala:236)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.handleTaskSetFailed(DAGScheduler.scala:730)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:1457)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:1418)
```

Comment: Since your second RDD is so small (110k), have you considered collecting and broadcasting it, instead of cogrouping RDDs (I know this is kind of beside the point, just saying...) ?

Comment: Yes indeed i have tried several things for joining two RDDs but every time reduceByKey part required too heavy shuffling.

Comment: Try increasing `spark.akka.frameSize` to keep up with the number of tasks you are producing with 10,000 partitions.

Comment: How can I decide an approximate number for `spark.akka.frameSize`? When set it to 1000, I still got the same errors that I mentioned in my post.

Comment: The problem is with the driver not executors (so not sure whether shuffling is the root cause) - note `ExecutorLostFailure (executor driver lost)`. Can you show the screenshots of standalone Master's and the driver's web UIs? You don't need to worry about `spark.default.parallelism` since you explicitly specified it via the number of partitions.

Comment: @mlee_jordan, the exception resolved ? I'm facing the same problem here [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47180307/how-to-use-cogroup-for-large-datasets/] any help please